# Set the value for the field annotated with @CreationTimestamp

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity that has a field annotated with `@CreationTimestamp`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
class Foo {
  ...
  @Column
  @CreationTimestamp
  private Instant createdAt;
}
```

And now I have integration tests where I need to create a few entries with different `createdAt` timestamps timestamp. But when I set the value to one that I need and save it's getting overridden with the creating timestamp of the VM:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setCreatedAt(Instant.MIN);
foo = fooRepo.save(foo);
foo.getCreatedAt(); // equals to the creation time
```

How can I insert the desired values for this field in my test env?

Comment: foo.setCreatedAt(Instant.MIN); will consider your underlying systems timestamp always.

Comment: @ScanQR What do you mean? It works the same if I set any other value, like `Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnits.DAYS)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to disable this behavior in an integration test as you need here.

However you can achieve the same using a workaround by setting the creation date after saving the entity, then save the entity once more to persist the new desired creation time.

This will work since `@CreationTimestamp` will only be triggered when saving the entity for the first time.

Comment: Thanks. But this workaround won't work if I would like to mark this field as `updatable=false`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `@CreationTimestamp` annotation, you could remove it from the field and manage that date with a `@PrePersist`:

```java
@PrePersist
void onCreate() {
    this.setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
}
```

Of course, you can check whatever you want in there. You could still have an `updatable=false` on the field.

Comment: I was thinking about this and there is actually another way. You can simulate running in the past (or the future) within your test using `java.time`.  It has two static methods which return thread safe implementations. First you have to define your point in the past with `Clock.fixed()` and then you rewind system clock to that point with `Clock.offset()`. From there, create and save your object and go back to present.